# how to assign a task result to variable while task is not finished yet

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to update a variable's value in an infinite loop.
a demo code of my situation is like this:

```py
import asyncio, random

async def coro1():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    global x
    x = 5

async def coro2():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    global x
    x = 10

async def main():
    global x # Edit
    x = 1
    while True:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            tg.create_task(coro1())
            tg.create_task(coro2())

asyncio.run(main())
```

my goal is to update `x` after all tasks are finished in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to assign a task result to variable while task is not finished yet

You don't - it really have to be finished so you get a result.

Of course, there is a problem with your question -  if it is an infinite loop, there won't be a moment when "all tasks are finished".

There are usually two ways of working with this: if the code following the creation of the task will need to consume the result, then it is time to `await` the task: Python will execute other concurrent tasks until this one is done, and the result will be returned, as far as the current code is concerned, as the result of the `await` expression.

The other way is to add a "done callback" to your task. If you want to group tasks, then you should gather then with  a call to `asyncio.gather`, for example, and call `.add_done_callback` on that. I don't think taskgroups as they are, have a way for one to schedule a callback when the task group is exited. In this case, the obvious way to code it is to simply call your desired code after closing the `with` block for the task group.

(Of course, as I mentioned, this example is a bit confuse - but it would run the "after" code after each cycle of all tasks: )

```
async def main():
    global x  # This is missing in your example
    x = 1
    while True:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
            tg.create_task(coro1())
            tg.create_task(coro2())
        x = 42  # this line will run after all tasks in the group
                # above are done. Since it is an infinite loop,
                # they will just start again
    return  #  and this line (not needed, just added for illustrative purposes) is just reached when something breaks the infinite loop.
```

Comment: Sorry for bad code